# File contents from a file are not displayes in php

Tags: php, webserver

```
if(file_exists('fileo'))
            {

                    chdir ("/home/fileo");

                    echo "You can view your result by clicking the link below.<br>";



                    echo " <a href = 'http://path/fileo'> Results </a> ";

            }
```

I have code like above for my php based web server to display the contents of fileo. fileo is the result from a perl program. Some times the web server displays file, but sometimes it does not. Only after sometime it displays the result, even if I do nothing. It seems to be very silly, but I would like to know if I am going anything wrong...sorry for such a naive question,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists('fileo')` will return true only if "fileo" exists in the same directory as the script being executed. If this code is being run from two separate scripts in separate directories, this can explain why file_exists() is sometimes not returning the value you think it should.

Also, `chdir ("/home/fileo");` is kind of strange, since chdir() expects a directory path, but `/home/fileo` is the path of a file. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: actually I have the fileo in the directory, but its not displaying sometimes. I have changed chdir to directory path but still its the same

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "not displaying sometimes"? Do you mean that you're clicking the link to `http://path/fileo` in your browser and a blank page comes up? (Also is that a valid path?) Because I don't see where in your code you are actually displaying the contents of "fileo".